# Confusion of the "if" instruction in WebAssembly

Tags: webassembly

Why do we need a "if" instruction since we could construct a "if" block with "br_if", "br" and "block" instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't remember all the nitty details of the discussions, but the short story is that we figured in the end that both are sufficiently useful in different circumstances. In particular, each may lead to more compact code in some context or the other.